# How to get two href with a condition in a button with php?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

On my page, I have a button that links to a form.
Right now, it s linked to the English version even when the page is in Spanish.
Is it possible to add a condition like, if the English version => link to the English version form and if it s the Spanish version link to the Spanish form?
On this button `<a href="/apply/" class="btn btn-light mt-5 pr-5 pl-5"><?php _e("Let's Grow", "mywebsite"); ?></a>`
The spanish link is /aplicar/

Thank you in advance!

```
<div class="banner bg-purple">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row d-flex align-items-center m-h-400 bg-img-building-blocks">
    <div class="col-6"></div>
       <div class="col-6">
         <h3><?php _e("we believe your potential", "mywebsite"); ?><br/><?php _e("is good business", "mywebsite"); ?>.</h3>
        <a href="/apply/" class="btn btn-light mt-5 pr-5 pl-5"><?php _e("Let's Grow", "mywebsite"); ?></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Sure that's possible. You just need to figure out what exactly the condition has to be, which variable you have to check on. But if this is supposed to link to an actual WP page, then it would probably make more sense, if you used WP functionality to generate the URL in the first place - then this should rather resolve to the correct language version automatically, depending on what translation/multilang plugin you are actually using.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, for this, I can t resolve it with the plugin (WPML), I have to fix it by the code, if you can provide a sample of the code it would be very kind. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why can't you just use `get_page_link` for this? The WPML plugin should hook into this, so that it automatically provides the correct link for the respective language version.

Comment: The code below works, thank you very much for your help. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`get_locale()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_locale/):

```
<?php $link = get_locale() == 'es_ES' ? 'aplicar' : 'apply'; ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url('/'. $link ) ); ?>" class="btn btn-light mt-5 pr-5 pl-5"><?php _e("Let's Grow", "ascendus"); ?></a>
```